# How to align QTextEdit text

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit

How can I align this text? `\t` is not good.

What I see (image)

[image]

Expected result (image)

[image]

Comment: Please provide [mcve] of your attempt.

Comment: Have you tried a fixed width font?

Comment: basicly use space before a number if the number is positive.

Comment: Use `QString::arg()`, quote from http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.7/qstring.html#arg : `fieldWidth specifies the minimum amount of space that a is padded to and filled with the character fillChar. A positive value produces right-aligned text; a negative value produces left-aligned text`.

Comment: If you don't need editing, you might want to write a custom `QWidget` subclass, where you paint the text so that it appears the way you want. You will need `QFontMetrics` to determine pixel width of various pieces of your text, and you probably need to do painting column-wise, or alternatively first go through text and calculate proper coordinates, then do actual painting afterwards. Or, as said, just use fixed width font (though in that case you will need similar approach, you will just have char column numbers instead of X coordinates to align).

Comment: `\t is not good.` is not a problem description. While it might be fairly obvious what you mean, you should still be clear about what is wrong, versus what you want to see instead.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem once in the past. To solve the issue I used **monospace** font.

To get everything aligned (fixed font width) I used these lines:

```
  // Use "monospaced" font: 
  // ->insure left column alignment, as for the terminal
  //
  QFont font("monospace");
  font.setPointSize(10);
  myQTextEdit->setCurrentFont(font);
```

from my parent widget containing a  [QTextEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html) child widget.

Comment: What if the second number in the '*' operation is 2 digit?

Comment: there are 2 problems: 1/ having a font with characters of fixed width, 2/ properly align everything with the right formatting. What I suggested must solve 1/, after to fulfill 2/ you must align what you want to print, for instance by using [QString.arg()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg). By example QString("%1 + %2").arg(10,5).arg(4,5) where I used a fieldwidth of 5 chars.

Comment: Any reason to prefer QFont("monospace") over [QFontDatabase::systemFont(QFontDatabase::FixedFont)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfontdatabase.html#SystemFont-enum)?

Answer (score 3):

this line:

```
QString str = QString("B%1").arg(_ui->lineEdit->text().toInt(), 3, 10, QChar('0'));

lineEdit->text() = 1 ,    str = B001
lineEdit->text() = 01 ,   str = B001
lineEdit->text() = 001 ,  str = B001
lineEdit->text() = 0001 , str = B001
lineEdit->text() = 12 ,   str = B012
lineEdit->text() = 123 ,  str = B123
```

you can adapt it for your use.

**Edit based on Hyde Comment**

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 qint32 a,b,c,d,e;

a = -1;b = 1;c = -1;d = 3;
e = (a*b) + (c*d);
QString str = QString("(%1*%2) + (%3*%4) = %5").arg(a, 2, 10, QChar(' '))
                                               .arg(b, 2, 10, QChar(' '))
                                               .arg(c, 2, 10, QChar(' '))
                                               .arg(d, 2, 10, QChar(' '))
                                                .arg(e);

QTextStream(stdout) << str << endl;

a = -1;b = 2;c = -1;d = 4;
e = (a*b) + (c*d);
str = QString("(%1*%2) + (%3*%4) = %5").arg(a, 2, 10, QChar(' '))
                                              .arg(b, 2, 10, QChar(' '))
                                              .arg(c, 2, 10, QChar(' '))
                                              .arg(d, 2, 10, QChar(' '))
                                               .arg(e);

QTextStream(stdout) << str << endl;

return 0;
}
```

the output is:

```
(-1 * 1) + (-1 * 3) = -4 
(-1 * 2) + (-1 * 4) = -6
```

Comment: How does this help OP produce the kind of output he wants?